# Python: Iterate through every pixel in an image for image recognition

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, image-recognition

I'm a newbie in image processing and python in general. For an image recognition project, I want to compare every pixel with one another. For that, I need to create a program that iterates through every pixel, takes it's value (for example "[28, 78, 72]") and creates some kind of values through comparing it to every other pixel. I did manage to access one single number in an array element /pixel (output: 28) through a bunch of for loops, but I just couldn't figure out how to access every number in every pixel, in every row. Does anyone know a good algorithm to solve my problem? I use OpenCV for reading in the image by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing every pixel with a "pattern" can be done with *convolution*. You should take a look at Haar cascade algorithm.